# Return newly inserted id into dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, sybase, sqlanywhere

Is there any way to retrieve newly inserted Id INTO DynamicParameters?
I use ODBC provider and Sybase.

Tried this solution so far but It doesn't seem to work

QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO Address
(
    Patron_SK_FK,
    Name
)
Values
(
    :PatronSKFK,
    :Name
) returning Address_SK into :Id;
```

CODE:

```
    protected override DynamicParameters CreateParameters(PatronAddress request)
    {
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

        parameters.Add("PatronSKFK", request.PatronSKFK, DbType.Int32);
        parameters.Add("Name", request.Name, DbType.String);
        parameters.Add("Id", DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

        return parameters;  
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 idea (not the best I reckon) - stored procedure, lock the table, insert, get max(id), unlock, select id - to return to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

The official way to retrieve values from a newly inserted record (without using the annoying `@@IDENTITY` - which is the professional way for `SELECT MAX(id)`) is:

```sql
SELECT new_rec.id INTO your_id_variable
FROM ( INSERT INTO Address ( Patron_SK_FK, Name) VALUES ( 'this', 'that' ) )
   REFERENCING ( FINAL AS new_rec );
```

This works trouble-free on SQL Anywhere (in queries or procedures). Don't know anything about your C# code however ....